# Building 64bit application with makefiles using cmake-gui

Tags: 64-bit, cmake

When I run `cmake-gui` and hit configure, I can specify the generator for my project. I can choose Visual Studio solution, Eclipse, makefiles etc...

I am on 64bit system and want to build 64bit application. Till now, I used Visual Studio 10 Win64 generator to generate my solutions. No I want to (have to) build it with makefiles. But there is no options 32b/64b.

Are makefiles for 64bit build used by default (on 64b system) and for 32b only after using something like `export CFLAGS=-m32` inside my cmake files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Are makefiles for 64bit build used by default (on 64b system)

Right.

> and for 32b only after using something like export CFLAGS=-m32 inside my cmake files?

Right. The relevant variable is called `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` though.